# How to load a print friendly version of a page in HTML?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a master page inside which I've added two css files for print and screen medias:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Where I've added some codes for my css:

```
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-size:20px;color:red;}
  }
@media screen
  {
  p.test {font-weight:bold;}
  }
```

it works fine when user viewing the pages in the browser or when clicking on the print button of the browser.

But how to force the page to be shown in print media when browsing in my desktop (screen media)?!

Basically, I'd like to show a print friendly version of the page in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do directly with a media (or a media query) since you can't mark a "local" page or a web page.

HTML5 helps you with cache-manifest.

Docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html

your html must to have:

```
<html manifest="print.appcache">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

and the manifest must contains:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
print.css
```

Online you'll override print.css with theme.css (but pay attention on !important css attribs), offline you'll not have at all theme.css